# Are stably rational surfaces all rational?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $X$ be an irreducible surface such that $X \times \mathbb{P}^1$ is rational. Is it true that $X$ is rational?

If the field is not algebraically closed, the answer is no in general (see A.  Beauville,  J.-L.  Colliot-Thélène,  J.-J.  Sansuc  et  Sir  Peter  Swinnerton-Dyer, Variétés  stablement  rationnelles  non  rationnelles,  Ann.  of  Math. 121(1985)  283–318.).

If the field is algebraically closed of characteristic zero, the answer is yes.

**What happens when the field is algebraically closed, of positive characteristic?**

(one could ask the same for simply rationally connected surfaces).

Comment: I imagine that this is a simple application of Castelnuovo's criterion, which is valid in all characteristics.

Comment: At least to me, the question does not exactly fit with the title. The question "are stably rational surfaces rational" is rather whether $X\times\mathbf{P}^n$ rational (for some $n$) implies $X$ rational?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The result is true in all characteristics. See O. Zariski, Illinois J. Math. 2(1958), 303-315.